# Need help cleaning up search field in filemakerpro to accept "enter" key as submit

Tags: search, button, filemaker

So ill keep it short and sweet. I've been working in FileMakerPro for a couple days now and I've finally developed a search field to comb through the 1000's of records we have.

The problem: After typing in my criteria in the field I have to click a button next to the field(the button is the field called global search) in order to perform the Find Script that i have created. Id like for the users to be able to hit enter on their devices w/o having to click go to search.[image: Picutre of my table - the globalsearch is the button that has to be clicked in order to perform the script - i can provide the script if needed but i dont believe it is in this case]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up a script trigger on the field on the OnObjectSave trigger to perform your script.